# What's the best way to avoid copy-pasting code in a GitHub Repo

Tags: powershell, github, symlink

First off let me apologize if this is a really dumb question, I'm fairly new to GitHub having never used any form of source control before :(

I have written a Powershell function (named Output-CORE) that I use quite a lot across a few of my scripts and at the moment I am copy-pasting this into the root directory of each of the scripts that end up using this function.

This means anytime I update the Output-CORE function I have to edit every instance of it, which is getting tedious to say the least.

Is there a way I can have this function in one place in my repo and then have it symlinked or something to each of the directories?

I've done some reading but I'm not sure if symlinks would work on our infrastructure (the code is written on Windows 10 machines and the repo is cloned onto our Windows Server 2012r2 SCCM management system where it is used as the basis of packages to be deployed to user systems).

To give some clarity the structure of where Output-CORE lives in our GitHub:

`company-name\ITScripts\Output-CORE\Output-CORE.ps1`

and when it ends up copied into various folders it may look like:

`company-name\ITScripts\SCCM\[script folder name]\[dependencies folder]\Output-CORE.ps1`

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: If the script is in a fixed location in your repository you could dot-source it from its path relative to the repository root.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it is! I will do some research into dot-sourcing! Thank you again

Comment: Ah I got confused, I thought you meant dot-sourcing it from GitHub not powershell :P
Unfortunately that doesn't work in my use case.

Comment: Then you need to elaborate on your use case and the structures you have. Generally speaking, the best solution to your problem would probably be putting your function(s) in a PowerShell module, deploying that first, and importing the module in your scripts.

Comment: Use case is as follows:
Scripts are written and uploaded to GitHub, they are then pulled down onto our SCCM server for deployment into packages which then get pushed to users systems.
Therefore not all of the repo is replicated to a users system, only the packages we push via SCCM.
Therefore we have to copy each script referenced into the package and push it out.
I do like the idea of pushing the Output-CORE function to all our PC's as a module and may well explore that.

Comment: @SteveBrown what you want is called [Submodules then you can add that submodule to any other project you need it in.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: @prix that is perfect! thank you very very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this with a tiny amount of faff.
I made symlinks relative to the repo on my windows machine:

`mklink /D company-name\ITScripts\SCCM\[script folder name]\Output-CORE ..\..\Output-CORE`

which then means everything gets copied over to SCCM for distribution and I only have to edit the script in one place going forward.

You learn something new everyday :D